# create virtual directory, app pool using powershell

Tags: powershell

Create website, app pool using power shell. set created app pool to created web site. Change the app pool managed pipe line mode to classic. I need above 3 things using power shell.

Created app pool using below code, working fine

Import-Module WebAdministration
$iisAppPoolName = "TestAppPool"
$iisAppPoolDotNetVersion = "v4.0"

```
    cd IIS:\AppPools\

    $appPool = New-Item $iisAppPoolName
    $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value $iisAppPoolDotNetVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $appPoolName = "your app pool name"
    $managedRunTimeVersion = "v4.0"  # your .net framework
    $managedPipelineMode = 1  # ([int] [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ManagedPipelineMode]::Classic)
    $physicapPath = "the physical path for your application"

    $IISPath = "IIS:\AppPools\$appPoolName"

    if (dir $IISPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        { Write-Output "`t`t$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): Application pool `'$appPoolName`' already exists"; return }

    New-Item $IISPath -Force | Out-Null

    Set-ItemProperty $IISPath -name ManagedRunTimeVersion -value $managedRunTimeVersion
    Set-ItemProperty $IISPath -name ManagedPipelineMode -value $managedPipelineMode

    New-Item $IISPath -physicalPath $physicalPath -type Application -Force | Out-Null
    Set-ItemProperty $IISPath -name applicationPool -value $appPoolName
```